# Open Source alternative to lablife

Tags: web-services, open-source, saas

I am looking for an Open Source alternative to SAAS provided by [lablife.org](https://www.lablife.org/ll) website. Main purpose of the service is to automate daily tasks for life science laboratory.

This service was free and nice to use, but when the original company developing this service
was bought by BioData they kind of decided to kill and replace it with a new service called labguru. Apparently, a new service has a lot of functionality missing or just bad.

That's why I am on a search for an alternative solution. So if you are familiar with what this software does - and if there are any known alternatives, I would be very grateful for any of your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Quartzy.com. I'm one of the founders.  Feel free to reach out with any questions.

Comment: not really open source, but is free and definitely is an alternative!